# Time Series Data - Scatter Plot Matrix

Tags: time-series, data-visualization

If I have two time series data, does it makes sense to plot a scatter plot matrix due to an dependent variable time?

[image]

I'm asking this question because you cannot perform pearson's correlation without using cross correlation with time series data, and I'm wondering if the same applies to scatter plot matrix?

Comment: How do you construct a $4\times 4$ scatterplot out of only *three* variables ("two time series data" plus, perhaps, time itself)??

Answer (score 2):

It makes sense in some cases to plot the scatter plot matrix to understand the relationship between the two time series (for the same timestamps). For example: if you have a time series of a person's height and the other is of person's weight then it would make sense to plot a scatter plot between height and weight to see how one varies with the other.